# How do I load a file using a button on MFC?

Tags: visual-c++, button, mfc, load

Basically I've created a mfc dialog with a button saying load. I just want to do what it says on the tin. If anyone could help I'd be grateful. I'm guessing it's something to do with the CFile function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment at hyperflow's answer:

[CFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk77e5e7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is your friend. [It's very easy to use](http://www.dotnetheaven.com/Uploadfile/mahesh/CFileDialogTutorial05242005022553AM/CFileDialogTutorial.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Put this inside your load button clicked event.

```
    CFileDialog l_fDlg(TRUE,NULL,NULL,OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT,"Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|Comma Separated Values(*.csv)|*.csv||");
    int iRet = l_fDlg.DoModal();
    CString l_strFileName;
    l_strFileName = l_fDlg.GetPathName();

    if(iRet == IDOK) {
        try 
        {
            CStdioFile file(_T(l_strFileName), CFile::modeRead);
            CString str,contentstr = _T("");

            while(file.ReadString(str))
            {
                contentstr += str;
                contentstr += _T("\n");
            }
        }
        catch(CException* e)
        {
            MessageBox(_T("Error"));
            e->Delete();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is great thank you but basically I want it to load the windows dialog with options to open various files rather than a specific file.

Comment: @bigbaz34: You should then clarify your question

Comment: My bad, I thought you already had the CFileDialog working. Check the code and I will update it.

Comment: @hyperflow: no, not *your* bad: The question was not correctly stated.

Comment: Thank you both for you help, I appreciate it. I will try and be more clear with my questions in the future.

Comment: @hyperflow I have added this code to my button handler however it is still coming up with several errors.



}